# cannot import xfeatures2d in python OpenCV binding

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, python-bindings

I am trying to access SIFT and SURF features from opencv 3 in python. As suggested by other people, I followed the installation of opencv_contrib. Some of the logs of the installation are:

```
[ 82%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d
...
Installing: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.0.0" to "/usr/local/lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/cuda.hpp
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp
```

After that I import cv2 in python but could not import xfeatures2d.

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

Any clue?

Comment: can you try a `cv2.__version__` (just to see, if it updated to 3.0) ?

Comment: its '2.4.8' ! How do I update the python binding?

Comment: regarding the (deleted) answer below, still, `cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` not cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT()

Comment: did you run `make install` ? (also, are there more snakes on your box?)

Comment: @berak, I used SIFT_create() as well. The problem is not able to find xfeatures2d, not SIFT. But lemme just update my question.

Comment: @berak, yes I did run make install. The `-- Installing:` log is I provided as from the install command.

Comment: yes, yes. prob is still, that it does not find the updated cv2.pyd, which should contain the xfeatures2d submodule.

Comment: @berak, do you know where is the updated cv2.pyd?

Comment: should be python/Lib/site-packages/cv2.pyd or similar